# How to pass object to another component in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I Am trying to figure out how can I add the items to watchlist,

The steps am trying to carry out here are, when a user clicks on add button, the items should be added to the watchlist page/component which I have created.

Please see the hierarchy of the component. I would like to show added items on the watchlist page.

[image]

Please see the code I tried.

```
const [watchlist, setWatchlist] = useState ([]);

const handleWatchlist = (movieData) => {
   const newList = [...watchlist, movieData]
   setWatchlist(newList)
   console.log(newList)
}




<Button className = {classes.cardButton}size = "small" onClick = {  ()=> handleWatchlist(movie) }> Add </Button>
```

When I try to inspect, the result is, it shows the items are added on the console as well into the state but can not pass on to the watchlist component? How can I use a prop to pass this value and show them in the watchlist component? or is its props not the right way to pass any object into a component?

[image: ![enter image description here]

The result on the console is as below.

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.
Please find the link to the full code below

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/components/Products/Watchlist.jsx

Thanks a million

Comment: Your example is far from minimal reproduction of the problem :p (+the codesandbox never ends loading) My advice though would be to use the redux store to store the movies and link them to components. Check the quick start tutorial > https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

Comment: Are those two components in parent child relationship?

Comment: Hi @KartikDolas yeah, this please see the image above for help I have posted which is the order my component

Comment: There is nothing at all rendering your `Watchlist` component. Create a route for it that you are navigating to. You *could* pass a `watchlist` value in route state, but the state you want to pass is in `Products` while the links are in `Navbar`. You're state and logic is all over the place. Consolidate your movie "state" in a central common parent component that is accessible be all three components and pass the state and callbacks around as props.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese Sorry for asking this, by the above comment, do you mean to say that I remove my watchlist component from the main NAV and then create a single MAIN movie component and pass watch list component as a reference?  Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: You are pushing a `"/watchlist"` path, so I assumed you are trying to render *some* component on that route path. The rest just follows from [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so it's accessible from a common area.

Comment: @DrewReese indeed will give it a try, thanks a million sir for sharing your valuable experience

Comment: hi @DrewReese  just wanted to clear one last doubt, is the useContext or createConetxt hook also the right way to pass the data in this situation? As i was reading some article and watching some videos and thought I should as you this.

Comment: It could be, it extends on the idea of lifting state up, solves the issue of needs to explicitly pass state and callbacks down as props, A.K.A. props drilling. This frees up the intermediate components from being responsible for passing all props on to children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support, but I figured out the solution by using two approaches and they are

1. Which is **props drilling, i.e. is to perform the useState action** in my App.js which is my main page where I have product and watchlist component.
2. This is the best way I would suggest other people use as well is by using the **contextAPI and useContext hooks**. A simple and easy way to pass any data anywhere in the app.

Please see the full code with the working solution below on the codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/components/Products

The working app, where I can add the products to the watchlist.

[working demo app](https://m2mtn.csb.app/products)

Answer (score 1):

upon checking out your code, you made a mistake when passing the props.
Currently you are doing this:

```
const Watchlist = (watchlist) => {
```

You should destructure and get the props first by doing this:

```
const Watchlist = ({ watchlist }) => {
```

Comment: Hi @MohdYashimWong I tried the way you said but seems like the application got crashed

Comment: Do you have an updated codesandbox i can check out?

Comment: Hi I have updated the code in the sandbox after the destructuring of the object as you suggested.

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/components/Products/Watchlist.jsx

Comment: `import React from 'react';

const Watchlist = ({
        id,
        title,
        poster_path
    }) => { 
        console.log(title)
        return (
            <> 
                <div > 
                    <h3>{id}</h3>
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                    <img  src ={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${poster_path}`}  />
                </div>
    </>    )
    }

export default Watchlist;`

Please see the code on my watchlist component after destructuring.

Comment: @TapeshPatel I am not understanding your code, but read 'method as prop'. it will help you.

Comment: Hi @KartikDolas Thanks for the help, really appreciated it, but I figured out a way around this.